# Need help on comparing DateTime through Slick

Tags: scala, slick-3.0

Code:

```
 def getDatasetStats(startDate: DateTime, endDate: DateTime) = {
    val query = for(created <- datasets) yield created.createdOn
    db.run(query.filter(d => d >= startDate && d <= endDate).size.result)   
  }
```

Table:

```
protected class Datasets(tag: Tag) extends Table[SqlDataset](tag, "datasets") {
    // format: OFF
    def id = column[UUID]("id", O.PrimaryKey)

    def name = column[String]("name")

    def createdOn = column[DateTime]("created_on")

    def updatedOn = column[Option[DateTime]]("updated_on")

    def isPublic = column[Boolean]("public")

    def * = (id, name, createdOn, isPublic, updatedOn) <>
      ((SqlDataset.apply _).tupled, SqlDataset.unapply)

    implicit def jodaTimeMapping: BaseColumnType[DateTime] = MappedColumnType.base[DateTime, Timestamp](
      dateTime => new Timestamp(dateTime.getMillis),
      timeStamp => new DateTime(timeStamp.getTime)
    )

    // format: ON
  }
```

The above solution i have tried is not working properly. Also i could not use isBefore or isAfter since i am getting Rep[DateTime] from DB. I need help on applying the date range filter on top of the result.

Answer (score 1):

`isBefore` and `isAfter` does not work. You have to use `<`, `<=`, and `>`, `>=`.

Slick is built on top of JDBC. JDBC understands `java.sql.Timestamp` only. So provide `implicit` mapped column type for joda `DateTime`.

```
 implicit def jodaTimeMapping: BaseColumnType[DateTime] = MappedColumnType.base[DateTime, Timestamp](
    dateTime => new Timestamp(dateTime.getMillis),
    timeStamp => new DateTime(timeStamp.getTime)
  )
```

Now you can use `<`, `<=`, `>` and `>=`

`>` is equivalent to isAfter and `<` is equivalent to isBefore.

**Have `implicit` in the scope where ever you are dealing with `DateTime`**

table

```
protected class Datasets(tag: Tag) extends Table[SqlDataset](tag, "datasets") {

implicit def jodaTimeMapping: BaseColumnType[DateTime] = MappedColumnType.base[DateTime, Timestamp](
      dateTime => new Timestamp(dateTime.getMillis),
      timeStamp => new DateTime(timeStamp.getTime)
    )

def id = column[UUID]("id", O.PrimaryKey)

def name = column[String]("name")

def createdOn = column[DateTime]("created_on")

def updatedOn = column[Option[DateTime]]("updated_on")

def isPublic = column[Boolean]("public")

def * = (id, name, createdOn, isPublic, updatedOn) <>
  ((SqlDataset.apply _).tupled, SqlDataset.unapply)

}
```

Method

```
def getDatasetStats(startDate: DateTime, endDate: DateTime) = {

implicit def jodaTimeMapping: BaseColumnType[DateTime] = MappedColumnType.base[DateTime, Timestamp](
          dateTime => new Timestamp(dateTime.getMillis),
          timeStamp => new DateTime(timeStamp.getTime)
        )

  db.run(datasets.map(_.createdOn).filter(d => d >= startDate && d <= endDate).size.result)   
}
```

Comment: I tried the above one, now i am getting like ">=" or "<=" not resolved error.  I copied the same code and past it under the place where i am dealing the DateTime comparison.

Comment: @Akan paste the implicit in ur table and in ur method

Comment: `db.run(query.filter(d => d >= startDate && d <= endDate).size.result)`
The **d** type says "d: nothing" now, previously it was "d:Rep[DateTime]"

Comment: @pamu Be really careful, `new DateTime()` will use the default local timezone where the code is executing, timestamps rely on `UTC`, you should have `new DateTime(timestamp.getMillis, DateTimeZone.UTC)`

Comment: @Akan this is very straight forward and i use it everyday ... I think ur doing something fancy ... can you post the table code as well

Comment: @pamu Sure i will, got an issue with compilation. Will try the solution once i am done with that.

Comment: @pamu I have posted the tablel,  can you take a look?

Comment: @Akan `implicit` is in table and in the method as well

Comment: @pamu Tried it as mentioned. Now in the line `db.run(query.filter(d => d >= startDate && d <= endDate).size.result)`  symbols "<=" and ">=" goes unresolved. Type of "d" says "d:nothing"

Comment: @Akan how can `d` be nothing. it should be `Rep[DateTime]`

Comment: @Akan `db.run(datasets.map(_.createdOn).filter(d => d >= startDate && d <= endDate).size.result)` instead of `query`

Comment: @Akan edited `getDatasetStats` in the answer PLease check

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125908/discussion-between-akan-and-pamu).

Answer (score 0):

My bad. The solution which i have tried works actually. The problem is with the pattern conversion which i have used to convert a string to DateTime.

Problematic code:

```
 val dtf = JDateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyymmdd")
```

Modified:

```
 val dtf = JDateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyyMMdd")
```

mm -> miniutes

MM -> Month

Since i have used **mm** in lower case to mention the month which yields me improper results. Now i am getting proper results after the change.