# slick schema projection issue with date

Tags: scala, slick-3.0

I am trying to create a schema for a simple table in slick 3.2. I am pretty new to scala so this might be a stupid question. When I try to remove date projection seems to work fine and I am able to run select query fine , but when I add date , I am not able to even compile code .

Below is my schema code :

```
import slick.jdbc.OracleProfile.api._
import java.sql.Date

class User(tag: Tag)
  extends slick.jdbc.OracleProfile.api.Table[(Long , String , Date)](tag, "USR") {

  def usr_arch_dt : Rep[Date]= column[Date]("USR_ARCH_DT")
  def usr_id : Rep[Long] = column[Long]("USR_ID", O.PrimaryKey)
  def usr_subj_txt : Rep[String]= column[String]("USR_SUBJ_TXT")

  def * : (Long, String,  Date) =
    (usr_id , usr_subj_txt , usr_arch_dt) // I see mentioned error here

}
```

Exception or error I see is in Intellij is  :

Expression of type Rep[Long] doesn't conform to expected type Long.

If I am able to compile this code , I am looking to search based on date range something like

```
val filterQuery: Query[User, (Long, String , Date), Seq] =
        ntfns.filter(_.usr_arch_dt > Calendar.getInstance().getTime )
```

Thank you !

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your `def * : (Long, String, String, Date)` has an extra `String`.

On date search, your filter query won't work as `java.sql.Date` comes with limited methods.  A common practice in Slick is to create an implicit mapper between `java.sql.Date` and the more feature-rich [Joda Time](https://github.com/JodaOrg/joda-time):

```
import scala.slick.driver.JdbcProfile.MappedColumnType
import java.sql.Date
import org.joda.time.DateTime
// ...

implicit def dateTimeMapper = MappedColumnType.base[DateTime, Date] (
  dt => new Date(dt.getMillis),
  d => new DateTime(d)
)
```

Here's a related [SO link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40082935/need-help-on-comparing-datetime-through-slick).

Comment: Will try Joda time and let you know.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @Leo, extra String was a typo, I removed it from the question now for others benefit. Below code worked for me :

```
case class User(tag: Tag)
  extends slick.jdbc.OracleProfile.api.Table[(Long , String , Date)](tag, "USR") {

  def usr_arch_dt : Rep[Date]= column[Date]("USR_ARCH_DT")
  def usr_id : Rep[Long] = column[Long]("USR_ID", O.PrimaryKey)
  def usr_subj_txt : Rep[String]= column[String]("USR_SUBJ_TXT")

  def * = (usr_id  , usr_subj_txt , usr_arch_dt)
}
```

I still need to look at filter, I will try your method and let you know the outcome.