# Using Scala Slick retrieve all records from SQL db where date from timestamp column falls in the last month or last week

Tags: mysql, scala, slick

Timestamp in SQL db is of type `datetime` and value is stored in the format `2020-05-10T10:58:38.559Z`. I have to retrieve all records from SQL db where date from timestamp column falls in the last month or last week.

Being new to slick I am unable to find the way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you have to make sure you have mapping for `java.time`/`joda.time` data types. They are described already in [other answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40082935/need-help-on-comparing-datetime-through-slick).

Once you have a table defined in Slick with a support for data types you could do something like:

```
// depends on your domain's definition of "last month"
val beginningOfLastMonth: Instant = ...
val endingOfLastMonth: Instant = ...

tableQuery.filter { row =>
  row.timestamp >= beginningOfLastMonth &&
    row.timestamp <= endingOfLastMonth
}
.result
```

Once you calculated what is "last month" and "last week" you can just use this range comparison to build query which would return all results for them.